# How exactly does the T-Virus turn people into zombies?

Tags: video-games, resident-evil

We all know that the T-Virus in *Resident Evil* (the one in the video games, not the movies) turns people into zombies, but how exactly does the zombification process work?

The sources I find all seem to conflict with each other on this (one site says that the virus toughens the infected but in turn damages their nervous system and causes necrosis, making them look like reanimated corpses when they are actually still alive, while another site says the virus revives dead people and turns them into zombies). So what's the canon explanation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Resident Evil Wiki](https://residentevil.fandom.com/wiki/Tyrant_Virus) states:

> By 1978, the development focus shifted from creating a lethal, highly contagious virus to one that would mutate hosts to become physically stronger and remain alive despite organ failures and severe brain damage. The latter led to murderous aggression and an obsessive hunger that drove individuals to cannibalism.

The wiki provides a canon source, the "[Wesker Report](https://web.archive.org/web/20011102192858/http://www.capcom.co.jp/bio5th/wesker/index.html)", which was produced by Capcom.